# Are there other ways to generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

For a topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ is defined as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all the open sets. This is done by taking the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing $\mathcal{T}$.

Are there other ways to do this? Is there a simple way to characterize this (e.g. in linear algebra, the smallest subspace containing a set is given as the set of all *linear combinations*)?

If not, is there some intuitive/logical reason why not; why can't there be a simpler description/characterization, say in terms of certain basic operations (e.g. linear combinations, in the case of subspaces of vector spaces)?

I am particularly interested in the usual Borel algebra on the real numbers (that is, $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intersection of all sigma algebras formulation is sort of a "top down" characterization.  You can also think "bottom up": start with a basis for the topology and then add in all complements, countable unions, countable intersections, and so on.  The reason this definition is sometimes avoided is that although it sounds constructive it does not give much of an idea of what an arbitrary Borel set must "look like" (and maybe there is a concern that students would form an erroneous guess about what they look like).

You may be interested in the "Borel hierarchy" of descriptive set theory, which goes into considerable detail in discussing sets in this space. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy

Comment: Ok. So is it not quite accurate to say that Borel sets are those formed by taking complements and countable unions/intersections of open (or closed) sets/basic open sets? Are there simple examples of Borel sets that aren't quite "constructible" in this way?

Comment: You just can't get everything in a finite number of steps of unions, countable intersections, and complementation. A book on the Borel hierarchy likely provides complete examples of things that you need one more step of sigma algebra operations to do. I don't know a good reference. They're not pleasant to look at (for me).

Comment: Borel sets **are** those formed by taking complements and countable unions/intersections of open (or closed) sets. 

However, you can't get the complete Borel $\sigma$-algebra even with a countable infinite number of steps. To produce the Borel $\sigma$-algebra by transfinite induction, we need to go till $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal.